# htaccess rewrite path to multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite URL1 to URL2. Can anybody help?

URL1:

```
http://www.localhost.de/stellenangebote/ort/hannover/200
```

URL2:

```
http://www.localhost.de/path/to/my/script.php?location=hannover&radius=200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache uses basic regexes for rewriting so you can use multiple capture groups "()" and reference them using $1 for the contents of the first capture group, $2 for the second and so on. In your case the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^stellenangebote/ort/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+) /path/to/my/script.php?location=$1&radius=$2
```

Comment: This won't work because of the leading slash, see [RewriteRule - What is matched?](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Changing `/stellenangebote/...` to `stellenangebote/...` should work.